# Using designated initializer with Structs in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, struct

I wanted to test a very simple code but Visual Studio 2010 isn't compiling it. It's the first time I am using designated initializer with structs but it appears to be 100% correct since it's just a simple copy and paste from the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29#Struct_initialization).

The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Forward declare a type "point" to be a struct. */
typedef struct point point;
/* Declare the struct with integer members x, y */
struct point {
   int    x;
   int    y;
};

/* Define a variable p of type point, and set members using designated  initializers*/
point p = {.y = 2, .x = 1};

 int main()
{
    point p2 = {.y = 3, .x = 4}; //not even inside main it works
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio marks the dots in .y as red. Does anyone knows what's going on? I searched for other references in the internet and I can't see why my code is wrong. Is VS2010 not supporting a C feature?

Comment: Designated initializers are available since VS2013 only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 `c` compiler supports only C89. Designated  initializers are a C99 feature.

Comment: Really?! So it took microsoft 14 years to comply with a standard? haha

Comment: Even now they still only have partial C99 support.